# Is there any solution to the lack of manual focus?

Tags: camera, huawei, front-camera

The Huawei P20 pro, and possibly other Huawei devices, seems to lack a manual focus (or perhaps even a good autofocus) in the front camera app. This can be an issue for close-up photos.

Is there any way around this? Installing other apps, rooting the phone, installing a different ROM...?

Comment: Not all front cameras are capable of adjusting focus by hardware?